# android update project com.android.sdklib.internal.project.projectproperties fails

Tags: android, eclipse, ant

I am trying to run the android update project command on a project i am working on.

After running the command i am presented with the following error. When i run this command on another project it works fine.

I have tried deleting the entire workspace and just checking everything out again and it still is not working.

```
VERSIONS
Hierarchy Viewer Version: 15.0.1.v201111031820-219398

Traceview Version: 15.0.1.v201111031820-219398

Dalvik Debug Monitor Service Version: 15.0.1.v201111031820-219398

Android Development ToolkitVersion: 15.0.1.v201111031820-219398
```

---

```
C:\Users\me\android-sdks\tools>android update project -p C:\Users\me\workspace\foo\bar\Framework
Updated local.properties
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.android.sdklib.internal.project.ProjectProperties.parsePropertyFi
le(ProjectProperties.java:385)
        at com.android.sdklib.internal.project.ProjectProperties.load(ProjectPro
perties.java:229)
        at com.android.sdklib.internal.project.ProjectCreator.updateProject(Proj
ectCreator.java:605)
        at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.updateProject(Main.java:693)
        at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.doAction(Main.java:273)
        at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.run(Main.java:119)
        at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.main(Main.java:102)

C:\Users\me\android-sdks\tools>
```

Comment: Which version of the tools are you using? They made some changes to fix some bugs that may be related to this in r15. Also this blog article might help: http://pjeutr.com/node/3

Comment: @CharlieCollins Thanks for the help, i found my problem in the `ant.properties` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My `ant.properties` file was corrupted. There was some stuff in there that was not correct. I basically just cleared the `ant.properties` file and re-wrote some of the stuff there and it works fine now.